# ExtJS app navigation using browser back button

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have an ExtJS (version 4.1.1) application with a single JSP page but multiple screens created using Ext JS components. When I click on the back button in the browser, I want to display the *last visited screen* within the application, rather than using the browser's default behavior of redirecting to the *last visited web page*.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`Ext.util.History`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.util.History) class, which is designed to track navigation through the browser's "back" and "forward" buttons. The basic idea is that when the user visits a new screen in your application, you call [`Ext.util.History.add()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.util.History-method-add) with an identifier token for that screen. Then, when the user clicks the browser "back" button, a [`change`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.util.History-event-change) event is fired with the token of the screen the user has navigated back to, which you would use to re-display that screen in your application.

The ExtJS documentation has a [history example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/history/history.html) showing how this can be done. The key portions of the code look like this:

```
function onTabChange(tabPanel, tab) {
    var newToken;

    // ... construct a token for the new tab ...

    oldToken = Ext.History.getToken();

    if (oldToken === null || oldToken.search(newToken) === -1) {
        Ext.History.add(newToken);
    }
}

// ...

Ext.History.on('change', function(token) {
    if (token) {
       // ... set active tab based on token ...
    }
});
```

Using `Ext.util.History` can often require a lot of boilerplate to set up if there are a lot of screens in your application, so ExtJS 5 added built-in [routing](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/application_architecture/router.html) to help manage this. There are extensions for ExtJS 4 that are intended to accomplish the same thing, such as [`Ext.ux.Router`](https://github.com/brunotavares/Ext.ux.Router) by Bruno Tavares.